# Smart pointers' control block internal machinery

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I'm wondering what are the exact conditions to release memory allocated for the internal control block shared by shared_ptr and weak_ptr.
I guess control block contains a shared_ptr counter and a weak_ptr counter.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Dummy
{
    Dummy() { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~Dummy() { std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    auto dummy = new Dummy();
    auto wp = std::weak_ptr<Dummy>(); // pointing to nothing

    {
        auto sp = std::shared_ptr<Dummy>(dummy); // 1
        wp = sp; // 2
    } // 3
    std::cout << "Land mark" << std::endl;
}
```

1. Building a shared_ptr with dummy allocated memory. Control block is allocated, and it's Dummy pointer is set to "dummy"
2. Building a weak_ptr from shared_ptr. Both smart pointers are sharing the same address of control block.
3. Shared pointer is destroyed. Dummy dtor is called ("dtor" is printed before "Land mark"). Control block still lives until end of program.

Am I right about these comments ?
What happens (in details) within control block during these steps ?

Edit: What happens with make_shared case ?
There is one allocation containing Dummy object and control block.
Does this involve placement new to use two differents objets ?
Or is it a structure containing a raw object ?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Dummy
{
    Dummy() { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~Dummy() { std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    auto wp = std::weak_ptr<Dummy>(); // pointing to nothing
    {
        auto sp = std::make_shared<Dummy>();
        wp = sp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what valgrind massif shows for your test,  ( if you are not used to valgrind ) this is the amount of memory allocated by time, first the pointed to object, then the count manager, and after that, the pointed to object is disallocated

[image]

This is basically how it works, when the last shared_ptr goes out of scope, the pointed to object is deleted (its memory disallocated), but the count manager is still there because the weak_ptr needs to know what is happening, if there is a pointed to object or not.

However sometimes this is not the case, if you use `make_shared`,  `make_shared` uses actually only one allocation for both the object and the count manager, in this case, the memory allocated will stay there until the last weak_ptr goes out of scope

Comment: Do you mean Dummy allocated object cannot be deleted when you are using make_shared in my case ?

Comment: The object is destroyed (the destructor is called) but not disallocated

Comment: I'm not fully satisfied of answers about details but I guess your answer is the most relevant.

Comment: Here is a [cppcon video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GWjbRpMHn0), explaining this very well,  he talks about shared_ptr after 9:40

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are right.

Detail of what happens :

1. The control block is created and bound to the `share_ptr`. `shared_count = 1`, `weak_count = 0`.
2. The `weak_pointer` binds to the control block. `shared_count = 1`, `weak_count = 1`.
3. The last (only) `shared_pointer` dies, destroying the object. The control block is maintained by the `weak_ptr`. `shared_count = 0`, `weak_count = 1`.
4. *(end of `main()`)* The last (only) `weak_ptr` dies, and `shared_count = 0`. No one is bound to the control block anymore, so the last `weak_ptr` destroys the control block.

Comment: You're a controlling block

Comment: @SombreroChicken I must keep going on for the weaks' sake -- that's heroic enough, I like it.